# Voltage Drop on circuit

Tags: schematics, 5v, voltage

I am a relative newbie, so please be kind.

This is a working schematic. When I press the buttons, the LEDs light up. So far, so good.

1. now I connect the multimeter to one of the M* pins and measure the
   voltage.
2. then I press only the button where the multimeter is connected.
   I get my great 5V.
3. if I press another button (one with only
   a LED on it) there is a voltage drop of ~0.6V on my multimeter on the first pressed button line.
4. if I also press the third button, the voltage drops another ~0.3V.

So if I press all the keys at once, I lose 1V!

I thought if I put 5V in the 'line' and everything is in parallel, there will be no drop on the individual lines? Do I have a thinking error here?

Pressing 0 buttons: 0.09V
Pressing 1 button: 5.08V
Pressing 2 buttons: 4.67V
Pressing 3 buttons: 4.5V

P.S.: You can ignore component *J4*; it will be used later to change the status with an ESP.

[image: Insert image description here]

Edit: Here is the PCB also:
[image]

Edit 2: Power Supply
[image]

Comment: Which one of the M* pins are you connecting to?  1 or 2?

Comment: The multimeter I have on M1 for testing but should not make a difference due to the same build(?)

Comment: I mean are you on pin 1 of M1 or pin 2?

Comment: I have the multimeter connected to M1.1 and M1.2 to measure the voltage

Comment: Nothing plugged into J4, right?   That means you have 3 "independent" circuits that are affecting each other - Their only commonality is they all share the same power supply.  What are you using for a power supply?

Comment: Can you monitor the voltage on your 5 V supply while pressing 0, 1, 2 and 3 buttons? Add the results into your question. The power supply could be inadequate.

Comment: @KyleB correct! I use a adjustable trafo I can plug in the home power socket from 5V to 12V

Comment: @Transistor updated the question with the results

Comment: What's the voltage between 5V and ground before and during the button presses?  And the voltage at the base of Q1?

Comment: @vir before button press the power supply has 5.2V. When I press the button it has 4.52V. Q1: 0.0V, when pressing 0.8V

Comment: Would you mind showing us a picture of the power supply and wiring?

Comment: @JonathanS. It is a PCB so exactly like on the schematic and just power and GND of the power supply on my input pins

Comment: The problem isn't the circuit itself, it's the physical construction. If you have a PCB, show the layout as well. It's especially important that you show us the exact power supply you're using.

Comment: @JonathanS. just added the PCB to the question (Device* == M* just renamed it later) (The big resistors I made as THT to try out different values for the Q1, Q2, Q3)

Comment: This really, *really* isn't sufficient to give an answer. We absolutely need to see what kind of power supply you're using, as well as the wires that connect it to your board. It's not the circuit, and it's also not the PCB. Both are fine.

Comment: @JonathanS. Added a pic of the power supply specs. For connecting to the pcb I just use normal standard jumper wires from the broadboard

Comment: When you press the button, the 5V drops to 4.52, what happens when you press two buttons?  Three?  Since you have just LEDs on there that draw maybe 50 mA between all three of them, it's unlikely that you are overloading your power supply.  If you are using small gauge wire to hook up to the power supply, that could be the issue.  Try measuring the current supplied to the 5V rail while you press buttons.  Also note that you are using 5V on the 3.3V section

Comment: It's the jumper wires. Breadboard jumpers aren't exactly known for their low resistance. Use thicker wires and solder them directly to your board.

Comment: Huh.. just measured the jumper wires resistance and they have 1 Ohm resistance. Doesn't sound that much? Or is this a completely other level that I measure wrong here with this? You have a tip for me what I can look on Amazon for cables? So what do I need maybe?

Answer (score 1):

> Pressing 0 buttons: 0.09V Pressing 1 button: 5.08V Pressing 2 buttons: 4.67V Pressing 3 buttons: 4.5V.

Assuming that the first reading is a typo and should read '0 buttons: 5.09V' then it seems that your power supply isn't capable of supplying the required current or you are using really fine wires or have some resistance in the circuit somewhere that is causing the voltage to collapse as it is increasingly loaded.

Comment: The power supply can provide 1A of current or what do you mean?

Comment: The photo you've added shows that the PSU is rated at 2.4 A when set to 5 V so it should be OK. That means you have resistance in your power wiring or a bad connection somewhere.